# Have emacs incremental search place the cursor at the beginning of the match

Tags: emacs

I am trying to get out of evil mode, but one thing that is causing problems is that the forward incremental search places my cursor at the end of the match instead of the beginning. I very rarely want to have my cursor in the middle of the match which results in unnecessary keypresses to reposition the cursor. Is there a way to make the forward incremental search place the cursor at the beginning of the match instead of the end?

Answer (score 2):

You question is addressed specifically in the [Position of the Cursor after Searching](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementalSearch#toc4)
 section of the IncrementalSearch page on Emacs Wiki.  In particular, it shows you how to use `isearch-mode-end-hook` to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use `defadvice` to `isearch-exit`.

```
(defadvice isearch-exit (after move-to-match-beginning activate)
  (when (and isearch-forward isearch-success)
    (goto-char (match-beginning 0))))
```

Comment: I would suggest using `isearch-mode-end-hook` instead. In the hook function you can use that same code inside of a `(unless isearch-mode-end-hook-quit ...)` wrapper.